# UISearch not working within UITableview using Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am developing `UITableview` with Search option. Here, I am using `UISearchBar` for below tableview array of data.

```
var data:[(String,[String])] = []
var searchdata:[(String,[String])] = []

data = [("A",["apple", "air", "access"]),
        ("B",["ben", "body", "box"]),
        ("C",["cat", "cap", "corn", "cow"])]
```

My Tableview Source

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return searchdata.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return searchdata[section].1.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return searchdata[section].0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = searchdata[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
}
```

Here, I am using below SearchBar method with filter code, I want to make sure this is the right way I am doing because whenever I am trying to search I cant able to see Table data.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       searchdata = data.map({ (title:$0.0,object:$0.1.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText) })) }).filter { !$0.1.isEmpty }
       self.tableVIew.reloadData();
}
```

Comment: First of all you are strongly discouraged from using tuples as data source. Basically you have to display the data depending on the length of `searchText`. If it's empty show the data in `data` otherwise show the data in `searchdata`

Comment: It might be possible to figure out why your filtered `searchdata` is not right, but I would very strongly suggest first that you stop right now and use a custom struct instead of an array of tuples. Tuples are really bad practice, they are hard to read and write and reason about, and they are not intended as array elements or other permanent model data.

Comment: Thanks @vadian please provide your suggestion with some code sample. I am new to this.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Yes I agree your point. I am learning so can you please provide some sample code relevant my question? If you give it will be very useful to learn.

Comment: Please see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489343/uisearchbar-not-looking-for-information-in-tableview/56491529#56491529

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p438searchableTable3/ch21p718sections/RootViewController.swift is an example from my book. Notice how the data model is structured as well as the use of UISearchController to help filter the table during search.

Comment: @matt I am sorry cant able to understand.

Comment: You can download the project and run it yourself.